# recommendation for 10g sfp+ NICs

Tags: desktop, pcie, ethernet, network-adapter

I am looking to develop a 10Gbps ethernet system on a Kintex-7 FPGA. I want the FPGA to communicate with a PC for monitoring the data, configuration, etc., at 10Gbps.

I am using a PC with Intel i7, 2 Avago GTX transceivers and a KC705 evaluation board from Xilinx. There is an opportunity to install the eval board directly onto the PC. But I do not want that. I want to connect it via an Optical Fiber.

Since I am new to this field, I need some recommendations for a Network Card with Fiber Optic Channel (SFP+) for my PC(or a PC with this NIC).

Comment: I found one. This one is from Startech.
StarTech PCI Express 10 Gigabit Ethernet Fiber Network Card (PCIe x4).
It cost me € 280/- from Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest also looking for new or second hand Chelsio cards (T420-CR/T520-CR for optic OM2 LC SFP+ format, or other formats available, see their website) - they are quite frequent and cheap (well, as cheap as 10G goes) as used items on EBay, and very highly recommended - both pfSense and FreeNAS projects recommend them above Intel for 10GbE networks (as opposed to 1Gb where Intel is the standard). The -CR ensures they take the right transceiver, if you have an open hand on the transceiver format then Finisar SFP+ with OM2 LC-LC optic cable work trouble-free, also easily found and cheap on EBay or from networking suppliers.